# Security Concern - How to Prevent User and Password from Displaying in Form Data During Login in a .NET Web Application

Tags: asp.net, authentication, security, viewstate

How can I prevent sensitive information, such as the username and password, from being exposed in the Form Data section of the inspect element feature in a .NET web application, as depicted in the image below?

[image]

I have taken several measures to address this concern, including:

1. Utilizing the declaration to secure the form. `<form id="form1" runat="server" method="post">`
2. Enforcing the use of HTTPS (secure HTTP) for enhanced security.
3. Adding the configuration in the web.config file to safeguard ViewState information. `<pages enableViewState="true" viewStateEncryptionMode="Always" />`

Despite implementing these strategies, the issue persists, and the sensitive data is still visible in the Form Data section during a successful login.

Comment: But what is the concern here , this data will always be visible at the browser level , what you are looking at is how the browser sees the data . The data at this stage is vulnerable only to malicious browser extensions and / or key loggers when the password is typed. Other methods that you mentioned like HTTS will ensure the data is safe in transit. Best case you may use a client side Java Script library to encrypt or hash the password but that still does not protect the password from malicious browser extentions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @SoumenMukherjee. 
Actually, our security team is concerned about this and is requesting the removal of the username and password from Form Data. That's why I'm exploring ways to hide this information. As you mentioned there are some JavaScript libraries, can you suggest any that might be helpful for me?

Comment: :-) client side encryption is always tricky since the key is always available on the client it is only a matter of time before someone finds out where is the key, I would rather suggest to include MFA along side user credentials for login.

Comment: The MFA option is also available for the user. So, we are already using that. :-) However, we still need to satisfy our security team.